# While loop not working error: bad operand types for binary operator '!=' Java

Tags: java, error-handling, while-loop

I am trying to make a letter gusser in java but my while loop won't work. The error I am getting is

error: bad operand types for binary operator '!='
while (input != ranLetter){
^
first type:  String
second type: char
1 error.

I tried to converting ranLetter to a char but then the loop never stops.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int ranNum = (int)(Math.random()*26 + 97);
    char ranLetter = (char)ranNum;
    //This is just for testing
    System.out.println(ranLetter);
    
    String input = in.nextLine();
    if (input == String.valueOf(ranLetter)){
      System.out.println("FIRST TRY BTW!! the letter was " + ranLetter + ".");
    }

    else{
      int counter = 0;
      while (input != ranLetter){
        System.out.println("Nope :( try again.");
        counter += 1;
        input = in.nextLine();
      }
      System.out.println("Nice you got it. The letter was " + ranLetter + ". It took you " + String.valueOf(counter) + " guesses.");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: input != ranLetter => you compare a string with a char and because of this you have the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to compare a String against a char:

```
while (input != ranLetter)
```

change to this instead:

```
 while (!input.equals(String.valueOf(ranLetter)))
```

as well as `input == String.valueOf(ranLetter)` to `input.equals(String.valueOf(ranLetter)`

Answer (score 2):

You can't compare String and char,
moreover, you should use .equals() method to compare input and String.valueOf(ranLetter) because

```
"A" == String.valueOf('A')
```

is always false